# Drupal fullcalendar integration -> JSON Formatting?

Tags: javascript, 8

I am working on a custom fullcalendar (http://fullcalendar.io/) implemenation for a custom module of mine.

I have created an hook_menu that will provide the json output that contains the events that need to be placed onto the calendar:

```
function mymodule_fullcalendar_measurement_jsonfeed() {
$json = array(
 '0' => array(
   'id' => '182',
   'title'=>'My Event',
   'start'=>'2015-02-16 13:00:00',
   'end'=>'2015-02-16 16:00:00',
   'description' => 'event desc',)
 );

  $jsonstring = drupal_json_encode($json);
  drupal_json_output($jsonstring);
}
```

And an ajax call to the hook_menu like below:

```
events : '/my_module_fullcalendar/jsonfeed',
```

This returns a json string like this:

```
 [{"id":"182","title":"My Event","start":"2015-02-16 13:00:00","end":"2015-02-16 16:00:00","description":"event desc"}]
```

The fullcalendar does not recognise this format, because it expects an event object.

I tried to use eventDataTransform to convert this into a correctly formatted object (as stated here: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/), but not luck so far.

I'm pretty sure that this is a formatting problem, because when i change the full calendar jquery events property like this:

```
events: my_events
```

And use a variable to create a dummy object:

```
        var my_events = {
      events: [
        {
          title: 'event 1',
          start: '2015-01-04',
          color: 'tomato'
        },
        {
          title: 'event 2',
          start: '2015-01-09'
        },
        {
          title: 'event 3',
          start: '2015-01-09'
        }
      ],
```

Everything works perfectly...

For the record i am working with full calendar 2.2.7

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was pretty straight forward actually.

I replaced the jscon encode and json output like this:

```
drupal_json_encode($json);
drupal_json_output($json);
```

And now it runs smooth :-)